# Error when creating a DB in SQL SERVER ( cycles or multiple cascade paths)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cascade

I try to create DB in sql server 2008,
and got this error:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 34
>
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Viewers_FK1' on table 'Viewers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.
>       Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 34
>       Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

this is my SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE [ShemenHD];


GO 
USE [DBNAME1]
GO
CREATE TABLE Users( 
UserName VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
FullName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PhoneNum1 VARCHAR(20) ,
PhoneNum2 VARCHAR(20)
);  


CREATE TABLE Category( 
CategoryNum VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY, 
CategoryName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
); 


CREATE TABLE Request( 
RequestNum VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
RequestCreator VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
RequestCategory VARCHAR(15),
RequestSubject VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
RequestContent VARCHAR(2000) ,
RequestOpenDate datetime NOT NULL,
RequestCloseDate datetime  ,
RequestSLA datetime ,
RequestStatus VARCHAR(50) , 
RequestPriority VARCHAR(50) , 
IsProject BIT NOT NULL, 
RequestFile VARCHAR(500) ,


constraint Request_FK foreign key (RequestCreator) references  Users (UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
constraint Request1_FK foreign key (RequestCategory) references  Category (CategoryNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
); 

CREATE TABLE Viewers(
 UserName VARCHAR(50) ,
 RequestNum VARCHAR(30) 

 constraint Viewers_PK PRIMARY KEY (UserName, RequestNum),
 constraint Viewers_FK foreign key (UserName) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 constraint Viewers_FK1 foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum)  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );

 CREATE TABLE AdminNotes (
 NoteNumber VARCHAR(10) ,
 RequestNum VARCHAR(30) ,
 NoteCreator VARCHAR(50),
 NoteContent VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,

 constraint AdminNotes_PK PRIMARY KEY (NoteNumber, RequestNum), 
 constraint AdminNotes_FK foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
 constraint AdminNotes_FK1 foreign key (NoteCreator) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE 

 );


 CREATE TABLE RequestMessage (
 MessageNumber VARCHAR(10) ,
 RequestNum VARCHAR(30) ,
 MessageCreator VARCHAR(50),
 MessageContent VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,

 constraint RequestMessage_PK PRIMARY KEY (MessageNumber, RequestNum), 
 constraint RequestMessage_FK foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE  ,
 constraint RequestMessage_FK1 foreign key (MessageCreator) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE 

 );
```

What is the problem? I want to cascade only when update, which cycles it's cause?
and how can I solve it?

thank you!!

Comment: the message is pretty clear :) you cannot specify multiple on cascade based on the same master foreign key. I test and give you more detail

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is the fixed code with comment :
As explained you cannot use the same column for a foreign key in multiple table and do cascade, you can only cascade once.

```
CREATE DATABASE [DBNAME1];


GO 
USE [DBNAME1]
GO
CREATE TABLE Users( 
UserName VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
FullName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PhoneNum1 VARCHAR(20) ,
PhoneNum2 VARCHAR(20)
);  


CREATE TABLE Category( 
CategoryNum VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY, 
CategoryName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
); 


CREATE TABLE Request( 
RequestNum VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
RequestCreator VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
RequestCategory VARCHAR(15),
RequestSubject VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
RequestContent VARCHAR(2000) ,
RequestOpenDate datetime NOT NULL,
RequestCloseDate datetime  ,
RequestSLA datetime ,
RequestStatus VARCHAR(50) , 
RequestPriority VARCHAR(50) , 
IsProject BIT NOT NULL, 
RequestFile VARCHAR(500) ,


constraint Request_FK foreign key (RequestCreator) references  Users (UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
constraint Request1_FK foreign key (RequestCategory) references  Category (CategoryNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
); 

CREATE TABLE Viewers(
 UserName VARCHAR(50) ,
 RequestNum VARCHAR(30) 

 constraint Viewers_PK PRIMARY KEY (UserName, RequestNum),
 --constraint Viewers_FK foreign key (UserName) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, -- This cause error
 constraint Viewers_FK foreign key (UserName) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
 constraint Viewers_FK1 foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum)  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );

 CREATE TABLE AdminNotes (
 NoteNumber VARCHAR(10) ,
 RequestNum VARCHAR(30) ,
 NoteCreator VARCHAR(50),
 NoteContent VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,

 constraint AdminNotes_PK PRIMARY KEY (NoteNumber, RequestNum), 
 --constraint AdminNotes_FK foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE , --This cause error
 --constraint AdminNotes_FK1 foreign key (NoteCreator) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE --This cause error
 constraint AdminNotes_FK foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION , 
 constraint AdminNotes_FK1 foreign key (NoteCreator) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION 

 );


 CREATE TABLE RequestMessage (
 MessageNumber VARCHAR(10) ,
 RequestNum VARCHAR(30) ,
 MessageCreator VARCHAR(50),
 MessageContent VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,

 constraint RequestMessage_PK PRIMARY KEY (MessageNumber, RequestNum), 
 --constraint RequestMessage_FK foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE  , --This cause error
 --constraint RequestMessage_FK1 foreign key (MessageCreator) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE --This cause error
 constraint RequestMessage_FK foreign key (RequestNum) references  Request(RequestNum) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION  , 
 constraint RequestMessage_FK1 foreign key (MessageCreator) references  Users(UserName) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION 

 );
```